# In svelte, how to `console.log('yes')` when a variable changed?

Tags: javascript, svelte

```
let c = 0;
$: console.log(c);
```

If we want to print the value of `c` when it is changed, we can write like above.

Because `c` is used in `$` directive literally, so this statement can be reactive to `c`.

But what if I just want to `console.log('yes')` when `c` is changed?

```
let c = 0;
$: console.log('yes');
```

Obviously, the statement `console.log('yes')` is not reactive to `c`.

Furthermore, if I still `console.log(c)` but put it into a function:

```
let c = 0;
function log() {
  console.log(c);
}
$: log();
```

`log()` is also not reactive to `c`.

So, what can I do if the reactive code doesn't literally contain the variable which I want to reactive to?

Comment: A very good read on Svelte Reactivity with examples and explanations https://sveltesociety.dev/recipes/svelte-language-fundamentals/reactivity

Answer (score 73, accepted):

[I asked in Twitter](https://twitter.com/liyuanqiu/status/1149235193296773122), the answer from Svelte creator Rich Harris is:

> The most common way to handle that situation is
> `$: c, console.log('yes');`
> It does feel a bit weird, I know :)

Comment: Thanks for coming back with the answer, staring this for future reference. I really wish this was outlined in the svelte docs.

Comment: Wow, this is quite the golden nugget of info. I would not have guessed to use a comma-separated statement after `$:`, which is new to me anyway. Is this a valid/better way to operate than having to put `boo.far = boo.far` whenever you think it might make a difference, in terms of updating a state (cos sometimes for some reason I don't, while other times I do - it's still a bit of a mystery)?

Comment: One big problem with this is that it doesn't expose the previous value, so this will trigger on page instantiation as well as user triggered update.

Answer (score 9):

I have recently been playing with svelte and needed to call a function when a property changed.
In Vue you would do it with `watch`, but I could not find an equivilent in Svelte.
 In my project have done it like this:

```
let c = 0;
$: if (c) {
    console.log("yes");
}
```

I am not 100% sure if this is the correct way or not though.
Hopefully Rich Harris will chime in here as I would like to know.

Comment: I've @Rich_Harris in Twitter, if he responses, I'll sync here.

Comment: You may use shorter syntax like `$: c ? console.log(yes):null;`

Comment: One gotcha with this approach is if you want that code to run on every change, including a change from non-zero to zero. The `$: if()` approach won't run when the value becomes 0 (or any other falsy value).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
let c = 0;
$: if (c >= 0) {
    console.log("yes");
}
```

Comment: change `c` from 1 to 0 will not do log...but it's another thread about the false value in javascript.

Comment: your intention is to write `c` literally in $ statement, although it looks strange. It's a workaround, we can also write `console.log('yes' || c)` or `c; console.log('yes');`, but they are all ugly...

Comment: I updated my answer to include `0`. This if statement can be adjusted to include negative values as well should you need that.

Comment: `c; console.log('yes')` doesn't look so ugly to me

Answer (score 1):

It also works if you just use the changing variable inside whatever you want to do:

```
let c
$: if (condition) console.log(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys you got it all wrong.
You can just do

```
let c = 0;

setInterval(() => c++; , 5000);
$: console.log(c);
```

Because svelte compiler will notice console.log takes C as a parameter.
And because console.log is called using reactive statement.
It will call your reactive statement every times C changes, so every 5000ms