# How to monitor a variable and run a function every time the variable changes?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

It will be like the `on:change` event.

I am not using this event because in some svelte libraries this event is not emitted, and the implication is to use binding and `$`.

However, it seems that Svelte doesn't have a clean syntax for it.

I can only think of something like

```
$: {
    if (variable) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

where every time `variable`'s value changes, `doSomething()` will run.

But the use of `if` statement is weird.. What if `variable` is a boolean? This way the function won't run when the variable's value is false.

The idea is to run the function every time the variable's value changes, no matter what the new value actually is.

I also tried

```
$: doSomething(variable);
```

It works, but it is also weird because the function `doSomething` may not need an argument. In this case, the argument is purely for adding the `variable` as a dependency of this `$` syntax...

Also tried the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56987526/11752443, but this one simply doesn't work. And it is not mentioned in the doc (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56987526/11752443) either.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution suggested by Rich Harris does seem to work:

```
$: variable, doSomething()
```

Working example: https://svelte.dev/repl/c25bdd71c9764f1f809bd35737fbaeb9?version=3.53.1

Comment: Ah.. You are right. It wasn't working because I used anonymous function like `$: name, () => {console.log(new Date())}`. This form doesn't work and there is no error, so I thought the approach didn't work as a whole. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Note that the function also runs on initial load, not only after variable change. Sometimes this behaviour in undesirable